# ChekBoxList Not Noticing Selected, and not displaying value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkboxlist

Not picking up that something is selected, and not displaying the value.
When I debug the code and step-in:

VBCODE:

1. When Debugging the "li" after Each holds a value(ex286)
2. when I go to Item and open the box I get this:

Item = Argument not specified for parameter 'index' of 'Public ReadOnly Default Property Item(index As Integer) As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'.
Item = In order to evaluate an indexed property, the property must be qualified and the arguments must be explicitly supplied by the user.

3. the "li" after If holds a value(ex286), but the Selected is "FALSE" Do not know why.
4. After the =  li is the text and the  Value(286)
5. Another thing it only gives me the value for the first box value not the rest if I click them.

   ```
     Protected Sub LinkButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles LinkButton.Click

   For Each li As ListItem In CheckBoxList.Items
       If li.Selected Then
           Texttext.Text = li.Value
       Else                 
           Texttext.Text = "Give Up Loser!"
       End If
   NextEnd Sub
   ```

ASCX FILE

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxSelectAll" runat="server" Text="Select All" AutoPostBack="True" />
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList" runat="server"
  DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id"
  RepeatColumns="3"  ></asp:CheckBoxList>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetStuff" 
DataObjectTypeName ="DataTransfer.TheData"
TypeName="BusinessDelegate.DataBusinessDelegate">
 </asp:ObjectDataSource>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton" runat="server" Text="Here"></asp:LinkButton> 
<asp:Label ID ="Texttext" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

I have tried a few items from online but nothing worked correctly.

[Get all selected values of CheckBoxList in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988757/get-all-selected-values-of-checkboxlist-in-vb-net)

[ASP.NET, VB: checking which items of a CheckBoxList are selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629571/asp-net-vb-checking-which-items-of-a-checkboxlist-are-selected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with this.
The below code might work for you.

```
Protected Sub LinkButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles LinkButton.Click
    Dim cbChecked As Boolean
    For lItem = 0 To CheckBoxList.Items.Count - 1
        cbChecked = CheckBoxList.GetItemChecked(lItem)
        If cbChecked Then
            Texttext.Text = CheckBoxList.GetItemText(lItem)
        Else
            Texttext.Text = "Give Up Loser!"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

When you run this above code, if the last check box is not checked then you will end up with 
'Give Up Loser!' in the 'Texttext' text box.

You can get the number of checked boxes in the list by using the below code

```
Protected Sub LinkButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles LinkButton.Click
    Dim checkedBoxes = CheckBoxList.CheckedItems
    Dim checkedBoxesCount = checkedBoxes.Count
    For Each lItems In checkedBoxes
        Dim chkdCheckBoxName = lItems.ToString
    Next
End Sub
```

Try this below code to write the values of checked boxes in the text box.

```
Protected Sub LinkButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles LinkButton.Click
    Texttext.Text = "" 'clearing the text box
    Dim checkedBoxes = CheckBoxList.CheckedItems
    Dim checkedBoxesCount = checkedBoxes.Count
    For Each lItems In checkedBoxes
        Dim chkdCheckBoxName = lItems.ToString
        Texttext.Text = Texttext.Text & " | " & chkdCheckBoxName
    Next
    If checkedBoxesCount = 0 Then
        Texttext.Text = "Give Up Loser!"
    End If
End Sub
```

> Above code is based on System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox

Comment: I am trying to get the values of the selected boxes to display in the label, but the code does not say the values or even know the boxes have been selected

Comment: @Someone I have added a new code to the answer based on your comment.

Comment: I will. Ill let you know.